# PHP algorithm, print values for each x,y,z coordinates

Tags: php, algorithm, loops

I have this case where I know what the output should be but cant think of how to do it:

I have three coordinates, x, y, z

```
$x = 2;
$z = count(range(0, 1)); //this will result in number 2 but I need the values to be displayed when printing inside the loop like below.
$y = 2;
```

now, I need to go on a for loop eight times (2x2x2) and print these values:

```
1 1 0
2 1 0
2 0 1
2 2 0
2 1 2
1 1 1
2 1 1
2 2 1
```

I have started doing it like this but not sure if its a proper start:

```
$get_total_spots = $z * $x* $y;

for ($i = 0; $i <= $get_total_spots ; $i++) {
  //at least I know using this loop it will iterate 8 times
}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you explain how you get these seemingly arbitrary numbers.. are they based on a formula that uses z x and y somehow?

Comment: @Laurens yes, basically, imagine a Rubicon and each square inside it represents 3 values (x,y,z), so, for each one of them I need to have the x,y,z coordinates. How can I do that?!

Comment: how big are these numbers? if they're small enough you can just use 3 for loops to print the values

Comment: @pew007 it can be bigger or even smaller than the ones I presented.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what exactly you mean, but if you want to print all positions (x,y,z) of each box of a rubics cube, assuming values of 0, 1 or 2, you can make 3 loops:

```php
foreach (range(0, 2) as $x) {
    foreach (range(0, 2) as $y) {
        foreach (range(0, 2) as $z) {
            echo("$x $y $z <br>");
        }
    }
}
```

results in:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 2 0
0 2 1
0 2 2
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 2 0
1 2 1
1 2 2
2 0 0
2 0 1
2 0 2
2 1 0
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 2 0
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

Where each line represents one square box of the rubics cube

Comment: thanks I will give it a try tomorrow, too tired right now

Comment: well the values can be very different. And Z is always a range of two numbers, which can be for ex. -6 to +8 . So would it still be the same for loops like you posted?

Comment: sorry but this wont work in my case as the coordinates changes all the time, so it can be different sizes of the rectangular. its not always a cubic

Comment: Then please explain in a bit more detail what it exactly is what you want. With the limited amount of information you are providing, nobody can help you..

Answer (score 1):

This seems similar. I don't follow the use of `range()`, so I might have this all wrong.

```
$spot = fn() => random_int(0, 2);

for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) {
    echo sprintf('%d %d %d%s', $spot(), $spot(), $spot(), PHP_EOL);
}
```

Gives (random sequence):

```
1 2 1
0 2 0
0 2 1
2 0 0
2 1 2
2 0 0
1 2 0
1 1 2
```

https://3v4l.org/6cVsM

Comment: Here's a literal take for you: https://3v4l.org/3EKgo

Comment: thanks but in my case cannot in any case be by random. These are some coordinates - unique for each square of the rubicon

Comment: I literally have no idea what you're trying to do.